# Aggregation on list forEach and maps improvals

Tags: java, iterator, lombok

I am using a function in a SpringBoot @RestController, with Lombok

This function is an intermediate result that permit me to do an aggregation between two classes.

This 2 classes are:

```
@Data
public class AchMatiereCmdCptAggDto implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4022154955808447185L;
    private String codService;
    private String codSociete;
    private String numCompte;
    private String codCommande;
    private Double mntCommandeHTLCY;
    private Double mntLivreHTLCY;
    private Double mntFactureHTLCY;
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class AchMatiereCompteCommandeAggFullDto extends AchMatiereCmdCptAggDto implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6357406952790844723L;
    private Date dateCommande;
    private String codFournisseur;
    private String libFournisseur;
    private Boolean booFournisseurIntragroupe;
    private Long idCommandeEtat;

}

public static String stringConcat(String ... elements) {
    return new StringBuilder().append(elements).toString();
}
```

I use them that way, and I want to improve *forEach* part, and any other improvable piece of code:

```
 public List<AchMatiereCompteCommandeAggFullDto> mergeAchat(List<AchMatiereCompteCommandeAggFullDto> achats,


List<AchMatiereCmdCptAggDto> achats2) {

    Set<AchMatiereCmdCptAggDto> setAchats = new HashSet<>(achats2);
    Map<String, AchMatiereCmdCptAggDto> map = setAchats.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    p -> stringConcat(p.getNumCompte(), p.getCodCommande()),
                    p -> p, (ach1, ach2) -> ach2
            ));

    achats.stream().forEach(achat -> {
        String k = stringConcat(achat.getCodSociete(), achat.getCodService(), achat.getNumCompte(), achat.getCodCommande());

        if (map.containsKey(k)) {
            achat.setMntFactureHTLCY(map.get(k).getMntFactureHTLCY());
        }
    });
    return achats;
}
```

I was thinking about using a `StringBuilder` for the concatenation of attributes.

I would also like to avoid *forEach*, and use a `Map` or something like this.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From java 8 it is available in the `String` class the method [join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) that achieves the same result of your method `stringConcat` so instead of:

```
String k = stringConcat(achat.getCodSociete(), achat.getCodService(), achat.getNumCompte(), achat.getCodCommande());
```

You can use `String.join` with `""` delimiter:

```
String k = String.join("", achat.getCodSociete(), achat.getCodService(), achat.getNumCompte(), achat.getCodCommande());
```

It is also possibile to avoid *forEach* and use `Map` instead but because you are modifying the `achats` list elements, you have to map every element of the list to a new instance of your class and after you obtain your new list. To achieve this you can define a new copy constructor for the class:

```
achats.stream()
    .map(original -> {
        String k = //omitted for brevity : see above the code for k
        AchMatiereCompteCommandeAggFullDto copy = new AchMatiereCompteCommandeAggFullDto(original);
        if (map.containsKey(k)) {
            copy.setMntFactureHTLCY(map.get(k).getMntFactureHTLCY());
        }
        return copy;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList()); //<- return the new list
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is String.join better than StringBuiler ? in terms of performance for example ?
On the other hand, in terms of performance, do you think that its better without forEach ?

Comment: @DrissNejjar,  in this case if you would to use `StringBuilder` , you should iterate over fields of you class , appending them in your stringbuilder and after convert it to `String`, instead with `String.join` you have already a method to do it. In terms of performance your custom method maybe is better, but I don't think you can notice it in a complicate code. For the second question, the use of `map` implies the creation of a new list of modified old elements (all new instances) and  I prefer your old solution `forEach`.  Probably the use of `stream` is an overkill, better loop over list.

Comment: Okey for `StringBuilder` and `String.join`.
if you think that stream is an overkill, what do you suggest instead ? when you say loop over list, do you think about a for loop ?
Thanks

Comment: @DrissNejjar Yes, just a `for` loop of list and inside call the setter method if condition is true, so no use of `Stream` in this case.

Comment: I tried the code, but I don't get the same result. Could you provide the way you have created `AchMatiereCompteCommandeAggFullDto` constructor please ?

Comment: If you want to use `Map` solution you have to define a copy constructor or equivalent method to create new instances of your class and after obtain the new list; otherwise if you don't want to touch code of your class use your `forEach` solution you already have.